# Run the Intuit Sync Manager, my newly items can't add to QuickBooks

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Using QuickBooks IPP V3.2.0.2, I am creating items that added without errors to the cloud. 
When I run the Intuit Sync Manager, my newly added items enter error state. These items do not exist in QuickBooks Desktop 2013 and these items with a status of pending, before I run the sync manager.

How to solve this question?

Comment: Please use v2, update endpoint to update the errored objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Query endpoint, you can try the following query

select * from Item where status='SyncError'

If you find the Item object in errored state then use the V2 status(deprecated) API to get more details.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_deprecated/qbd_v2/qbd_v2_reference/0600_object_reference/syncstatus#Retrieving_Status

**PN -** QBD APIs(V2 and V3) are deprecated

You should post these qts in Inuit's **live community -**
https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/

Thanks